# Rsync returns “such file or directory” when running command

Tags: linux, rsync, logging

I am new to Linux and I am using rsync in order copy logs from one server to another but the command I am running says directory not found. What is going wrong?

```
001 rsync -u -avze ssh /apps/container-log/* user@xxxxx.com:~/apps/test-rsync 
user@xxxxx.com.com's password: 
sending incremental file list 
rsync: change_dir#3 "/local_home/user/apps" failed: No such file or directory (2) 
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(614) [receiver=3.0.6] 
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender] 
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605[sender=3.0.9]
```

Comment: i have checked the server for the path

Comment: But did you check if "user" has permissions to read and write to the source and target directories?  [ These could be blocked by filesystem perms or SELinux or equivalent ]

Comment: Yes user has the permission

Comment: Whaat Distro are you using, and have you tried disabling selinux, or looked at the log files on the destination system?

Answer (score 2):

Your command is:

```
rsync -u -avze ssh /apps/container-log/* user@xxxxx.com:~/apps/test-rsync
```

I would suggest you just remove the `~/` from the destination. And try it like this:

```
rsync -u -avze ssh /apps/container-log/* user@xxxxx.com:apps/test-rsync
```

But I am not too sure about the options you have setup, so I would recommend you use this command instead:

```
rsync -avz /apps/container-log/* user@xxxxx.com:apps/test-rsync
```

And even us the `--dry-run` option to see what the command will do without actually running it:

```
rsync -avz --dry-run /apps/container-log/* user@xxxxx.com:apps/test-rsync
```